# Java - Socket doesn't write correct hex values

Tags: java, sockets, hex

I write `int` array of hex values but when i read them some values are corrupted.
But when i read values before write it recognises them.
I notice that only byte values that are interpretated as negative integer result corrupted.
Someone has a solution?

> Start values: 4D|73|00|17|31|C2|00|A0|15|01|02|03|FF|FF|FA|5D

My class:

```
public class MySocket extends Socket {
    OutputStream os;
    OutputStreamWriter osw;
    BufferedWriter bw;    

    MySocket(String h, int p) throws IOException {
        super(h, p);
        os = this.getOutputStream();
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    }

    public void write(int[] str) {
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
                char s = (char)str[i];
                System.out.println("byte: " + (byte)str[i] + 
                        " -- char: " + (char)str[i] +
                        " -- int: " + str[i]);
                bw.write(str[i]);
            }
            bw.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         MySocket s = new MySocket("host", port); //connection is OK
         int[] hexarray = {0x4D, 0x73, 0x00, 0x17, 0x31, 0xC2,
                            0x00, 0xA0, 0x15, 0x01, 0x02,
                            0x03, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFA, 0x5D};
         socket.write(hexarray); 
    }
}

/* ------------------------------------------------
   ------------- OUTPUT ---------------------------
    byte: 77 -- char: M -- int: 77 -- hex: 4D
    byte: 115 -- char: s -- int: 115 -- hex: 73
    byte: 0 -- char:   -- int: 0 -- hex: 0
    byte: 23 -- char:  -- int: 23 -- hex: 17
    byte: 49 -- char: 1 -- int: 49 -- hex: 31
    byte: -62 -- char: Â -- int: 194 -- hex: C2
    byte: 0 -- char:   -- int: 0 -- hex: 0
    byte: -96 -- char:   -- int: 160 -- hex: A0
    byte: 21 -- char:  -- int: 21 -- hex: 15
    byte: 1 -- char:  -- int: 1 -- hex: 1
    byte: 2 -- char:  -- int: 2 -- hex: 2
    byte: 3 -- char:  -- int: 3 -- hex: 3
    byte: -1 -- char: ÿ -- int: 255 -- hex: FF
    byte: -1 -- char: ÿ -- int: 255 -- hex: FF
    byte: -6 -- char: ú -- int: 250 -- hex: FA
    byte: 93 -- char: ] -- int: 93 -- hex: 5D
*/
```

> Read values: 4d|73|00|17|31|**c3|82|00|c2**|a0|15|01|02|03|**c3|bf|c3|bf|c3|ba**|5d

Comment: And how do you read the values? To read and write from socket you need to implement some kind of protocol. Maybe in the reading part you read the data wrong? For example reading bytes or something like that

Comment: I read from serial channel of the shield where i write

Comment: This probably has to do with using different character encodings. If you just want to write bytes, you shouldn't be using a `Writer` (you are using `BufferedWriter`); `Writer` is for writing **text** (characters that are converted to bytes using a character encoding).

Comment: The error is in charset encoding because if i set `OutputStreamWriter` with `UTF-16` i read all values correct but between one and the other there is `'00'`

Comment: There is no such thing as a hex value. There are values, and representations, in decimal, hex, octal, ... You are writing *binary data*, which is *expressed in the source language* as hexadecimal, conveyed to the writing method as an array of 32-bit integers, and then further mangled by using a `Writer`. How you are receiving it, and how you are presenting it once received, remain your secrets. Don't code like this. To transfer binary data, use a `byte[]`, an `OutputStream`, `InputStream.read()`, etc. Fantasizing that this is due to `Socket` rather than your own poor coding is unproductive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `Writer`.  The `Writer` and `Reader` APIs are for reading and writing character data.  But you are writing binary data.

1. Use the `OutputStream` / `BufferedOutputStream` APIs.
2. You won't be able to write an `int[]`.  Use a `byte[]` instead.

---

> I notice that only byte values that are interpretated as negative integer result corrupted.

That is because `int` (or `byte`) is signed, but `char` is unsigned.  So when you cast a negative `int` (or `byte`) to a `char`, it is going to wrap around.

For example:

- byte 0xFF is -1
- when you assign that to an `int` you get 0xFFFFFFFF (also -1)
- when you cast that to a `char` you get 0xFFFF which is a Unicode codepoint in the ["Specials"](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf) code page.

In short, the "corruption" you are seeing happens because your code is converting bytes / integers to characters the wrong way.

---

> Socket doesn't write correct hex values

Actually, this is not `Socket` specific behavior ... and it will work if you use the APIs as they are designed to be used.   I recommend that you read the [Character and Byte Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html) section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: I tried but If i don't use a `OutputStreamWriter` and `int` array, the shield doesn't interpret the stream. Socket work correctly, the problem is in some values.

Comment: Show us the code that uses directly OutputStream that doesn't work.